# hibernate @ColumnTransformer not working on update named query

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, password-encryption

I am having the entity attribute like

```
@Column(name = "password")
@ColumnTransformer(forColumn = "password", read = "convert_from(decrypt( password, 'private.key', 'aes'),'UTF-8')", 
write = "encrypt(?, 'private.key', 'aes')" )
private String password;
```

when the select query is triggered i am getting the read values getting appended to the query ,

when insert query is triggered also i am getting write values appended to the column field ,

but when use update to update the password filed i am not getting the write operations to the field added
any idea on how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I am trying to update via named queries like                                                     
 "update user set password='newpassword' where  password='new password '",       i am expecting encryption and decryption take place instead hsql generated query is:                                                                                                                        
  update public.user set password='newpassword' where password='new password'